# PostgreSQL select query to extract latitude and longitude from a point

Tags: postgresql, latitude-longitude, point

What SELECT query should be used to extract latitude and longitude from a point?
**I cannot use PostGIS.**

Example point (point type value) stored in the database:

```
   my_point
--------------
(50.850,4.383)
```

Expected result after executing the query:

```
  lat  |  lng
---------------
50.850 | 4.383
```

The query below works fine but it does not look efficient.

```
SELECT 
    split_part(trim(my_point::text, '()'), ',', 1)::float AS lat, 
    split_part(trim(my_point::text, '()'), ',', 2)::float AS lng
FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Always [Read The Fine Manuals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html)

> It is possible to access the two component numbers of a point as though the point were an array with indexes 0 and 1. For example, if t.p is a point column then SELECT p[0] FROM t retrieves the X coordinate and UPDATE t SET p[1](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html) = ... changes the Y coordinate. In the same way, a value of type box or lseg can be treated as an array of two point values.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. The funny thing is I already read it before asking this question except the lines below the tables.

Comment: Worth noting that extracting it from a literal directly will not work:
Select point(25,55)[0]; -- will not work!!
You need existing point:
with a as (select point(25,55) p) select p[0] from a; -- will work!

Comment: @Valentin it works with parentheses: `SELECT (POINT(25,55))[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be:

```sql
SELECT 
    ST_X(point) as longitude, 
    ST_Y(point) as latitude
FROM your_table_name
```